# Linq and Entity FW database access and search in ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, linq, search, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to write a search function that will search trough the whole table and I'll get all columns, so far I'm using this code and I can only extract one column from the table, how can I get all columns.

CODE:

```
public ActionResult SearchIndex(string productsAll, string searchString)
        {
            var products = from m in db.Products
                         select m;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                products = products.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(searchString));
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(productsAll))
                return View(products);
            else
            {
                return View(products);
            }

        }
```

Please HELP :D

Answer (score 0):

You can filter based upon other columns as well...

```
products = products.Where(n => n.Name.Contains(searchString) ||
                               n.Prop2.Contains(searchString) ||
                               n.Prop3.Contains(searchString));
```

Which will get you any record which contains that string in any of the fields you specified.

Comment: Thanks Brocco I'm new to asp and I'm just graduating :)

Comment: No problem, you may want to revisit this method as well in regards to the productsAll parameter which will have zero effect on what this function will return.